# Google Feed API JSON output not showing latest records

Tags: json, rss, feed, google-feed-api

I am trying to load the feed using Google Feed API, but i am unable to get the latest records. I have tried below:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          url = 'http://www.propertyguru.com.sg/news-rss/SG-PM';
          var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
          $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=20&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&nocache=' + (new Date).getTime() + randomNum,
              dataType: 'json',
              historical: false,
              error: function () {
                  alert("Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed");
              },
              success: function (data) {
                  alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, "\t"));
              }
          });
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried pasting your AJAX URL into a web browser?

Comment: Use some REST client add on for firefox and test the REST url....

Comment: Your AJAX call succeeds but returns null.

Comment: there is something OFF with this RSS actually

Comment: From [this](http://www.propertywire.com/rss-feed/news/) feed also not getting latest records.

Answer (score 0):

You were incorrectly encoding the `q` url query parameter, and there was a problem with the `callback` parameter.  Try this URL instead:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&q=http://www.propertyguru.com.sg/news-rss/SG-PM
```

Comment: still i am not receiving the latest records

Comment: Paste the above url into your browser and tell me what you see.

Comment: i can see the records from "05 Feb 2015" and url have the latest record from "01 Apr 2015"

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this does not solve the problem. I have it too. It appered about a week ago. Untill then it worked perfectly.